# Can I install neo4j at each users computer?

Tags: neo4j, installation

I am using neo4j as server solution but was thinking of also using it in other situations. 
Is it, from a technical, installation, licensing perspective etc, possible to install neo4j at each users own computer for local storage of data? 
I would like to incorporate the neo4j db installation as part of my own software installation process to avoid technical problems for the end user.

It will probably only be very small set of data in each database so performance is probably not an issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you want every user to have their own local neo4j installation (since, for example, their local DBs will not contain the same data).

But, if you really wanted to, there is no problem (technically or legally) with installing the **community edition** of neo4j on multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

In this You Tube Video, about 30 minutes into it, "Neo4j Licensing: Which Edition Is Right For You" Rik Van Bruggen mention that one must contact neo4j if one want to distribute neo4j together with other software. One possible solution, according to the video, is an OEM agreement. One need to discuss the commercial terms.
He also says that it is not allowed to be done with the Community Edition

It also written at neo4j.com/licensing that

**"I want to include Neo4j in software that I’m shipping. What are my options?**

Neo4j offers a mature OEM program tailored to your needs. Learn more →"